# Does loopback 4 has embeds one and embeds many relations available?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I am migrating my LoopBack 3 application to LoopBack 4. in lb3 application i was using embeds one and embeds many feature in my model but unable to find same relation in lb4. By the documentation. it has yet to be implemented. Is the documentation outdated or is it not available? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, `EmbedsOne` and `EmbedsMany` relations are not implemented at the moment. The focus is currently on implementing and improving SQL relations.

A workaround is to use the `HasOne` and `HasMany` relations. However, it is not officially supported by StrongLoop.

Comment: what about [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.embedsmany.html) in the lb4 docs?

Comment: These add metadata to the Model, but those metadata will not be honoured by the ORM; This is so that other third-party libraries can utilise LB4 Models if they wish to.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot see in the relations when you try to add. But in this issue they presume they fixed it. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2130

Here is the usage example.

```
@model()
export ExampleMainClass extends Entity{
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id: string;

  @property()
  key: ExampleSubClass;
}

@model()
class ExampleSubClass{
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

}
```

Create a model and than inside of that model class write your sub module. And add that as a property to your main module. Then it will be okay.